# Fast way to use String.Contains with huge list C#

Tags: c#, database, performance

I have somethings like this:

```
List<string> listUser;
listUser.Add("user1");
listUser.Add("user2");
listUser.Add("userhacker");
listUser.Add("user1other");

List<string> key_blacklist;
key_blacklist.Add("hacker");
key_blacklist.Add("other");

foreach (string user in listUser)
{
   foreach (string key in key_blacklist)
   {
      if (user.Contains(key))
      {
           // remove it in listUser
      }
   }
}
```

The result of listUser is: user1, user2.

The problem is if i have a huge `listUser` (more than 10 million) and huge `key_blacklist` (100.000). That code is very very slow. 
Is have anyway to get that faster?

UPDATE: I find new solution in there.
http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string
Hope that will help someone when he got in there! :)

Comment: Is keeping it as a Dictionary an option?

Comment: Can you use any other data structure?

Comment: The list is the wrong collection for this. `HashSet` would be hugely better.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, @Jon How will `HashSet` help when you're checking whether strings *contain* other strings?

Comment: @Rawling that's a gotcha ... thank you!

Comment: @tinhve are you sure you need `.Contains` and not `.Equals`?

Comment: @tinhve As this is tagged `database`, presumably your 10 million items are stored in a database. The correct thing to do is get the database to do this, but for us to help you with that we need to know what kind of database you're using and how you access it.

Comment: Sub-string searches are always slow. But why do you add this user in the first placel? If you don't add him  you don't need to remove him later. Also, as Rawling has already mentioned, what database are you using? Do you want to delete them from the database?

Comment: I just use string, not data structure. @Tim Schmelter: I must search substring so I am finding a solution for this

Comment: @tinhve: what's wrong with using a specific data structure?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have much control over how the list of users is constructed, you can at least test each item in the list in parallel, which on modern machines with multiple cores will speed up the checking a fair bit.

```
        listuser.AsParallel().Where(
            s =>
            {
                foreach (var key in key_blacklist)
                {
                    if (s.Contains(key))
                    {
                        return false; //Not to be included
                    }
                }

                return true; //To be included, as no match with the blacklist
            });
```

Also - do you have to use .Contains? .Equals is going to be much much quicker, because in almost all cases a non-match will be determined when the HashCodes differ, which can be found only by an integer comparison. Super quick.

If you do need .Contains, you may want to think about restructuring the app. What do these strings in the list really represent? Separate sub-groups of users? Can I test each string, at the time it's added, for whether it represents a user on the blacklist?

UPDATE: In response to @Rawling's comment below - If you know that there is a finite set of usernames which have, say, "hacker" as a substring, that set would have to be pretty large before running a .Equals test of each username against a candidate would be slower than running .Contains on the candidate. This is because HashCode is really quick.

Comment: From the example blacklist and user names, I think it's pretty clear that he *does* need `Contains`.

Comment: But what isn't clear is whether he can avoid doing this by organising the usernames a little differently? Why does the blacklist need to contain sub-strings instead of a complete set of those blacklisted?

Comment: (I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying it's not clear what the other constraints are, and whether he can make it more efficient by taking a different approach)

Comment: It's a blacklist of substrings. `hacker` presumably will block any username with `hacker` *in* it. But I agree with "test each string, at the time it's added, for representing a user on the blacklist?"

Comment: @Rawling - Have updated my answer to take account of your comment

Comment: @Phil Whitington: I try to use 100 threads to check this, but it really slow too.

Comment: What about my other points? Do you really need to test .Contains? Do you not know the full set of blacklisted users? Either way, I suspect you need a different approach. As @Rawling said above, maybe get the database to do this work. But use a JOIN on the set of blacklisted users, don't get SQL to do Contains, for the same reason.

Comment: @tinhve - also bear in mind that 100 threads is overkill. Once you have more than one thread per core, it's likely that either not all the threads are being used or that the context switching is costing you CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using entity framework or linq to sql then using linq and sending the query to a server can improve the performance.
Then instead of removing the items you are actually querying for the items that fulfil the requirements, i.e. user where the name doesn't contain the banned expression:

```
listUser.Where(u => !key_blacklist.Any(u.Contains)).Select(u => u).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a tree-like data structure.

The basic idea is to have the blacklisted words organised like this:

```
+ h
| + ha
|   + hac
|     - hacker
|     - [other words beginning with hac]
| 
+ f
| + fu
|   + fuk
|     - fukoff
|     - [other words beginning with fuk]
```

Then, when you check for blacklisted words, you avoid searching the whole list of words beginning with "hac" if you find out that your user string does not even contain "h".

In the example I provided, with your sample data, this does not of course make any difference, but with the real data sets this should reduce significantly the number of `Contains`, since you don't check against the full list of blacklisted words every time.

Here is a code example (please note that the code is pretty bad, this is just to illustrate my idea)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program {

    class Blacklist {
        public string Start;
        public int Level;
        const int MaxLevel = 3;
        public Dictionary<string, Blacklist> SubBlacklists = new Dictionary<string, Blacklist>();
        public List<string> BlacklistedWords = new List<string>();

        public Blacklist() {
            Start = string.Empty;
            Level = 0;
        }

        Blacklist(string start, int level) {
            Start = start;
            Level = level;
        }

        public void AddBlacklistedWord(string word) {
            if (word.Length > Level && Level < MaxLevel) {
                string index = word.Substring(0, Level + 1);
                Blacklist sublist = null;
                if (!SubBlacklists.TryGetValue(index, out sublist)) {
                    sublist = new Blacklist(index, Level + 1);
                    SubBlacklists[index] = sublist;
                }
                sublist.AddBlacklistedWord(word);
            } else {
                BlacklistedWords.Add(word);
            }
        }

        public bool ContainsBlacklistedWord(string wordToCheck) {
            if (wordToCheck.Length > Level && Level < MaxLevel) {
                foreach (var sublist in SubBlacklists.Values) {
                    if (wordToCheck.Contains(sublist.Start)) {
                        return sublist.ContainsBlacklistedWord(wordToCheck);
                    }
                }
            }
            return BlacklistedWords.Any(x => wordToCheck.Contains(x));
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        List<string> listUser = new List<string>();
        listUser.Add("user1");
        listUser.Add("user2");
        listUser.Add("userhacker");
        listUser.Add("userfukoff1");

        Blacklist blacklist = new Blacklist();
        blacklist.AddBlacklistedWord("hacker");
        blacklist.AddBlacklistedWord("fukoff");

        foreach (string user in listUser) {
            if (blacklist.ContainsBlacklistedWord(user)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Contains blacklisted word: {0}", user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tree works fairly well if searching at the beginning of the string, but doesn't help at all for any other case.  Consider if a blacklisted word is "hacker" and a user has the name "ImNotAHacker".  The actual instance of a simple tree being able to significantly reduce the number of Contains() calls is pretty tiny for real-world data.  Otherwise, why do you think any RDBMS has to resort to a table scan when you say `WHERE column LIKE "%somevalue%"`?

Comment: @dodexahedron: if you have a single value to check against, you can't do better than a full table scan, but in this case (100k blacklisted words) this could do a difference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong thing. If you have a lot of data, you should be using either `HashSet<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`. If you don't need the data sorted, go with `HashSet<T>`. Here is a program I wrote to demonstrate the time differences:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Lists...");
        var stringList = new List<string>();
        var hashList = new HashSet<string>();
        var sortedList = new SortedSet<string>();

        var searchWords1 = new string[3];
        int ndx = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
        {
            string str = RandomString(10);

            if (x == 5 || x == 500000 || x == 999999)
            {
                str = "Z" + str;
                searchWords1[ndx] = str;
                ndx++;
            }
            stringList.Add(str);
            hashList.Add(str);
            sortedList.Add(str);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Lists created!");
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        bool search1 = stringList.Contains(searchWords1[2]);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("List<T> {0} ==> {1}ms", search1, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        search1 = hashList.Contains(searchWords1[2]);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("HashSet<T> {0} ==> {1}ms", search1, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        search1 = sortedList.Contains(searchWords1[2]);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("SortedSet<T> {0} ==> {1}ms", search1, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static string RandomString(int size)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

On my machine, I got the following results:

```
Creating Lists...
Lists created!
List<T> True ==> 15ms
HashSet<T> True ==> 0ms
SortedSet<T> True ==> 0ms
```

As you can see, `List<T>` was extremely slow comparted to `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`. Those were almost instantaneous.

Comment: My point in there is we have a huge list searchWords1 ~ 100,000 elements. So I have UPDATE in 1st post about compare .contain function to another way. And I want to ask the performace of .Contain. It very slow so I need another way to change .Contain function.